# Asynchronously redirect std output and err output to file

Tags: bash, io-redirection

I am trying to redirect the output of certain program with threads to certain file.

I have tried running `command > file 2&>1` but if `command` has not stopped running, `file` will still be empty.

Is there any way to asynchronously dump the output to `file`?

Example python snippet:

```
import _thread

def run():
    raise ValueError('plah')

_thread.start_new_thread(run, ())
while True:
    pass
```

Running `python program.py 2> log.txt` does not yield an output in `log.txt` until the program is manually stopped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the output [unbuffered](https://stackoverflow.com/q/107705).  A simple way to do this with Python is to set `PYTHONUNBUFFERED`:

```
PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1 python program.py 2>log.txt
```

Comment: Perfect! Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

Python buffers output by default.  Give the `-u` flag, or put `PYTHONUNBUFFERED=yes` to avoid that.